# Ruby on Rails deploy with capistrano throws ssh error

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I want to deploy a rails 3.2 app and in the console i see this error:

```
[deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection          failed for: IP_ADDRESS (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy)
connection failed for: IP_ADDRESS (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy)
```

my deploy file:

```
set :domain , "DOMAIN"
set :application, "APP_NAME"
set :repository,  "MY_REPO"
set :scm, :git
set :scm_verbose, true
set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/camplist_de/public/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :branch, "master"

role :web, "IP_ADDRESS"
role :app, "IP_ADDRESS"
role :db,  "IP_ADDRESS", :primary => true

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

after "deploy", "deploy:bundle_gems"
after "deploy:bundle_gems", "deploy:restart"


namespace :deploy do
task :bundle_gems do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle install vendor/gems"
end
task :start do ; end
task :stop do ; end
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
end
end
```

There are placeholders instead of domain and ip in this code here, not in my original deploy file.

I can't localize the error and need some help.

Comment: Can you ssh manually to the server?

Comment: yes. capistrano can create dirs but it will cancel when i try cap deploy:cold.
the deploy dependencies are ok.
cap deploy:setup works fine